# CloudFormation Lambda template, Expecting role to be string, when using Ref or GetAtt

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

When creating my lambda stack I am using a role called LambdaExecutionRole, I am then referencing the ARN through fn::GetAtt

```
"Role": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaExecutionRole","Arn"]},
```

, like the documentation said, I am then given the error saying that the specified resource does not support GetAtt. So I tried with GetAtt, and I am returned:

`Properties validation failed for resource GetECLambda with message: #/Code/S3Bucket: failed validation constraint for keyword [pattern] #/Role: expected type: String, found: JSONObject`

I also tried with `"Role":{ "!Ref" : "LambdaExecutionRole"},`

From my understanding one of these should have returned a String and therefore a String would be provided, not a JSON Object. But the issue may be that the String is defined like so: {"The Arn"}, but I am unsure how to avoid that.

The Structure of my lambda and the role are as follows:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
    "Description" : "Stack to create the get-EC lambda",
    "Resources" : {
        "LambdaExecutionRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [{ "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": {"Service": ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]}, "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole"] }]
                },
                "Path": "/",
                "Policies": [{
                    "PolicyName": "root",
                    "PolicyDocument": {
                        "Version": "2012-10-17",
                        "Statement": [{ "Effect": "Allow", "Action": ["logs:*"], "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*" }]
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        "GetECLambda" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Properties" : {
                "FunctionName": "get-ecs",
                "Role":{ "!Ref" : "LambdaExecutionRole"},
                "Runtime": "nodejs12.x",
                "Code": {
                    "S3Bucket" : "arn:aws:s3:::flex-fit-lambda-functions-source",
                    "S3Key": "get-ecs.zip"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you can not use !Ref for the JSON format. As You can see here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html !Ref is only for the YML format

Comment: Maybe this example can help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-lambda.html#quickref-lambda-example-1.json

Comment: @CyberEternal Yeah I spotted that so I replaced it with {"Ref" : "LambdaExecutionRole"} And I am still given the same error that a string was expected.

Comment: That's strange since I'm able to run the stack using `"Role": { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["LambdaExecutionRole", "Arn"] },`

Comment: @CyberEternal Apologies, thats not quite right what I said. I get this error: 
`Properties validation failed for resource GetEmergencyContactsLambda with message: #/Code/S3Bucket: failed validation constraint for keyword [pattern]`

Could this be something to do with my Bucket with the zip file in ACL? I havnt modified that, as I thought if I had access to it and I was executing the stack, it would use my permissions.

Ontop of that, I cant actually understand what that error message is trying to tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifying Cloudformation template in JSON, only this form of calling intrinsic functions is supported:

```
{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "logicalNameOfResource", "attributeName" ] }
```

`!Ref` form is only supported for YAML.
So try changing your current call to this in your template:

```
"Role": { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "LambdaExecutionRole", "Arn" ] }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that returns the following: `Properties validation failed for resource GetEmergencyContactsLambda with message: #/Code/S3Bucket: failed validation constraint for keyword [pattern]`

What is that error message actually telling me?

Comment: This answer fixed the String issue, the other issue is that I was using an ARN to specify the bucket, when you are meant to just specify the bucket name.

Comment: @OlliePugh Thank you for commenting on arn vs bucket name. That was exactly my problem as well. 